# Vuetify Pick Only Year (YYYY) from date

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How do I select only year from Vuetify Datepicker ?

I have a requirement where I need a drop down to select only the year `YYYY`.

But the default Vuetify date-picker picks the whole `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see in source code of date picker that `year` type is planned and will be implemented in future. From source code props:

> ```
>  type: String,
>   default: 'date',
>   validator: type => ['date', 'month'].includes(type) // TODO: year
> },
> ```

But I can achieve this with workaround `no-title`, preventing date picker to switch to month/day window and closing `v-menu`. You can see working example - [Changed codepen from docs](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yqVVKV).

You can play also with formatting title and header to get better result if you want.

Comment: That `year` dropdown is pretty much what I wanted exactly.But when I select an year, it is also selecting `01-19` by default.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't supported using the `type` prop.

But a workaround is setting `this.$refs.picker.activePicker` to type `YEAR`. We can create a watcher to watch the menu property, and change `activePicker` to `YEAR` when the menu is opened:

```js
watch: {
    menu (val) {
      val && this.$nextTick(() => (this.$refs.picker.activePicker = 'YEAR'))
    }
}
```

Next, we need to close the menu as soon as the user selects a year. We do it by adding `@click:year` event on the picker:

```html
<v-date-picker
    v-model="year"
    ref="picker"
    no-title
    scrollable
    @click:year="saveYear(year)"
>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn text color="primary" @click="menu = false">Cancel</v-btn>
    <v-btn text color="primary" @click="saveYear(year)">OK</v-btn>
</v-date-picker>
```

The `saveYear` method:

```js
saveYear(year) {
    this.$refs.menu.save(year)

    // Reset activePicker to type YEAR
    this.$refs.picker.activePicker = 'YEAR'

    // Close the menu/datepicker
    this.menu = false
}
```

Comment: This looked promising, but this code returns null for the "year". I would love to get a fix for this if possible.

Comment: `activePicker` is a property from `v-date-picker`. Direct mutations will raise a warning. Changing `internalActivePicker` may be a better idea

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
 <v-date-picker
    v-model="year"
    ref="picker"
    no-title
    scrollable
    @input="saveYear(year)"
>
</v-date-picker>
```

The saveYear method:

```
saveYear(year) {
  this.$refs.picker.internalActivePicker = 'YEAR'
}
```

The year watch :

```
year (val) {
   if (val){
      this.$refs.picker.internalActivePicker = 'YEAR'
   }
}
```